# IdentityServer Authentication for child websites

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-authorization

im trying to implement IdentityServer Authorization for 2 web sites where users can access 2 websites from Parent Website using windows authentication and i want to authorize the user for each API call from my website , please refer below image [website_authorization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dllGA.png)

Any suggestion or reference please

Thanks in Advance

Comment: https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @JessedeWit - Thank you and can you please suggest some code sample it will be more helpful

Comment: I can't give a code sample, because the question is too broad. Code samples you can find in that link. There's many code samples for different scenario's.